# FFmpeg RTSP to HLS Conversion is causing random freezes and errors

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nginx, rtsp, hls

So, I have a command that converts RTSP to HLS for me:

```
sudo ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer -rtsp_transport udp  -i rtsp://admin:'password'@10.2.10.201/video1  -vsync 0  -copyts  -vcodec copy  -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov  -an  -hls_flags delete_segments+append_list  -f segment  -segment_list_flags live  -segment_time 3  -segment_list_size 10  -segment_format mpegts  -segment_list /mnt/hls2/stream2.m3u8  -segment_list_type m3u8 /mnt/hls2/%d.ts
```

It seems to work just fine, but in the console, I'll get random errors along with an occasional warning about Non-monotonous DTS in output stream.

[One of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxlPG.png)

[More Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D2Yc.png)

[Another Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2vJm.png)

[Another Type of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bszJq.png)

[Last Error Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ1ip.png)

When I get the red errors, it seems to stop the stream wherever I'm viewing it from (Webpage, VLC, etc. Also seems to be worse on iOS for some reason) but it will come back just fine if I refresh the webpage or have VLC fetch the stream again. Could anyone offer any insight as to what's going on and how to prevent random cut outs while converting RTSP to HLS?

I'm using Nginx 1.15.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 if that helps which is set up to handle HLS streams and will handle them just fine from non-RTSP sources.

Edit: Sometimes I notice that it will just after going down pick up a random clip from another HLS stream being managed by nginx, could this be hinting at more of an nginx issue? That stream is simply using ffmpeg to stream HLS to the server directly from the camera of a raspberry pi and shouldn't be affecting anything on this stream.

Comment: For reasons not related to the question, I did change the segment time for HLS from 3 to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -rtsp_transport flag for this has to be switched to tcp and not be udp, udp is just causing a bunch of packet loss in this case which was causing all the issues, tcp is presenting no issues/errors.